# Как увеличить метку Яндекс-карты при наведении на неё?

Tags: яндекс-карты, карты

Образец реализованного:
https://realty.yandex.ru/search?type=SELL&category=APARTMENT&rgid=547386

При наведении на объявление с левой части экрана справа на карте увеличивается метка. Необходимо реализовать так же.

Есть ли возможность в яндекс.картах увеличить стандартную метку? Или только если другую картинку подгружать при наведении?

Спасибо!

Comment: @barakh-d, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/dg/concepts/geoobjects-docpage/#icon-style

Обратите внимание на опцию iconImageSize при использовании собственного изображения. И все, что ниже, тоже почитайте.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourCollection.events
.add('mouseenter', function (e){
    e.get('target').options.set({iconImageSize: [48, 86], iconImageOffset: [-24, -86]});
})
.add('mouseleave', function (e){
    e.get('target').options.set({iconImageSize: [30, 54], iconImageOffset: [-15, -54]});
});
```